# References in speculative applications

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

This is so far only a theoretical question, but at some point this year I will have to enter the academic job market and probably finally find a job "the normal way". Not that I never tried finding a job, I successfully found different jobs before. Still, I got all of these jobs in a rather informal way where if I had presented the formalities they did not seem to play an important role for the person hiring me. So basically I got my jobs by being curious enough in an interview, informal recommendation and previously working with the same person.

Somehow I suppose finding a post doc will finally throw me off this streak of luck. As now I am not yet as stressed out and busy as I will be when finally finishing to write up I am planning to prepare for the job hunt as early as possible.

Some institutes offer the possibility to upload a CV as a speculative application even though they currently do not have matching vacancies. I would like to do that, as I feel it makes me turn up on the radar and might even lead to some networking opportunities.

But one part of a good post doc application are the reference letters or at least mentioning people who would be references for me.

How is the etiquette for this? I do not want to *use* someone as a reference without them knowing about it and knowing where I will apply. But I also can't really tell them exactly, and don't want to bother them if I just upload it to a large institutes collection of CVs from potentially interested people.

Should/can I mention potential references, should I just not mention any and hope reference letters will be requested or should I ask everyone beforehand if they would be fine writing a letter for an yet unknown recipient in case I need it?
And, while we are at it, any other tips about informal speculative applications that I missed?

The field is STEM, I am currently in Europe but might apply outside Europe as well.

Comment: You need to mention your field and geographic area.  For mathematics in North America, applicants usually apply to a few dozen postdocs or over a hundred permanent positions (some of which may get a thousand applicants) at a time; reference letter writers usually write a generic reference letter and rarely even check where it's sent to - because it would be impractical to do so.  Other fields or geographic locations may differ.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I edited it in, although I have not restricted myself yet to which geographic region I am going to apply.

Comment: 'STEM' is too broad to be useful - biomedical fields, engineering, and mathematics behave very differently.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The usual format is to state 'References available on request' at the bottom of your CV. Then, if an insitituion is interested in your application, they can contact you to supply them with your referee details.

This approach will also give you notice so that you can inform your chosen referees beforehand that they may be contacted by a hiring institution.